# ImagePath doesn't always work

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-bitmap

I'm strugglin with this already all day :-( My current approach looks like this

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/image.jpg");
imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/image.jpg";
startActivityForResult(IntentUtils.dispatchTakePictureIntent(getActivity(), file), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

afterwards i do some unimportant stuff to make display the Bitmap correctly and then display it with this method

```
placeImageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
```

*EDIT This is how i create the Intent

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {

        if (file != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(file));
            return takePictureIntent;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works so far.

But when i use this `imagePath` in the next activity, the bitmap won't load. I already tried before so many things with this file path before, at the moment i just feel owerwhelmed by all the possible ways to handle this ...

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you defining imagePath on your second activity?

Comment: post how you load the bitmap in "nextactivity" ?

Comment: ok my mistake was different, i got a nullpointer, because i din't have the dimensions of the imageview and tried to do some calculations with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound trivial, but you have checked if the image really gets recorded where you want it to be - i.e. have you checked for the image by using the standard phone file explorer? (I would have posted this as a comment, but my reputation is too low.)